# Choose next non-empty cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table (Table A) containing 96 rows with data in them. There's a second table (Table B) that references Table A. In Table B there is a calculation that either copies the data from Table A or puts "" because the data is outside of a specified range (e.g., IF(A1<500,A1,""). The end result in Table B is several rows without data in them.

I'd like to create a Table C that references Table B, but only copies rows with data in them. E.g., if the data in Table B looks like this:

```
465
461
168

46


187
198
48
```

I'd like Table C to look like this:

```
465
461
168
46
187
198
48
```

Is there way to do this with a formula?

Thanks! Nikki

Comment: When you say "copy" are you using a formula to pass the values or vba code that actually copies the cell?  If either please [edit] your question to show the formula/code so we may further help.  This question is too broad and difficult to answer without knowing how the data is "copied"

Comment: I'm using a formula to pass the values.

Comment: The formula is too complicated an not relevant. An example is IF(A1<500,A1,"").

Comment: What is the formula, please add that to the original post using [edit]

Comment: The formula you use must be incorporated in the new formula, so it is relevant, and may also be simplified in the addition

Comment: Ah, I was trying to keep this simple! Ugh. Let me explain: I have a raw data tab and a calculated data tab. If a cell in the raw data tab has data in it (Q8:Q103), the values (A8:P103) are NOT copied to the calculated data tab. If another cell on the calculated data tab (T12:T107 - note the shift because there are more header rows) has data in it, the data (A12:S107) should NOT be copied to the GEF tab. These wells that determine if data will be copied or not are places where comments are made - a commnet mean data does not get transferred. The comment cells are some of the few unlocked cells.

Comment: I hope that it is clear that this is on a row by row basis, if there is data in cell Q100 on the raw data tab, all row 100 data will not be moved over to the calculated data tab. I need the blank rows on the calculated data tab, but I don't want them on the GEF tab.

Comment: Why the avoidance of actually providing the actual formula?

Comment: =IF(AND('Appendix 2 - 4 Hr Raw Data'!Q95="",'Appendix 3 - 24 Hr Raw Data'!Q95=""),'Appendix 3 - 24 Hr Raw Data'!B95,"")

Comment: And I have 2 raw data tabs that have comment cells that need to be considered, and 2 calculated data tabs. Which formula do you want?

Comment: I want the formula that is producing the list with the blanks.  The one you want to modify to exclude the blanks.  You have one list with blanks being produced that should be one formula.  It is that formula that needs to be modified, unless you want to use a helper column, to which I have responded in the comments to my answer how to modify my formula to use your current output with the blanks to create a third list without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$20)/($A$1:$A$20<500),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

This will skip the blanks as it is copied down.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What is the purpose of the 15 and 6 in AGGREGATE?

Comment: And can I substitute $A$1:$A$20="" for $A$1:$A$20<500?

Comment: The idea would be that you would adjust the formula that produces the list in the place of the `$A$1:$A$20<500` to get the list without additional helper columns and is why I asked for the actual formula.  As you can see I modified the simple formula you provided to be used in the above.  If you would provide the actual formula I will happily help adjust it to fit in this formula.

Comment: If you want the helper column then use `$A$1:$A$20<>""`

Comment: Okay, I can use this formula with the helper column, but in order to modify it to my needs, I still need to know what the 15 and 6 mean in the aggregate function. I will always have 96 rows of data. Thanks!

Comment: 15 is SMALL and 6 ignores errors.  see [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the range containing blank rows you want to remove.
2. Click Home > Find & Select > Go To Special.
3. In the Go To Special dialog box, check the Blanks option.
4. And then click OK, all of the entire blank rows are highlighted. Then click Home > Delete > Delete Sheet Rows, the blank rows have been deleted from the selected range.

You should try with this post:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2654-excel-dynamic-list-remove-blanks.html

Comment: Ah, yes, but these need to be locked cells that perform this automatically.

Comment: If the values are being brought in by formula then this will not work.

Comment: I guess I should have requested a calculation to do this! I will modify my question.

Comment: Thank you!! I will try that!

Comment: Can you tell me what each part of =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(ROW()-ROW($D$1),$A$2:$A$11,0)),"") does? I pasted it in, (modified for my spreadsheet) but it didn't work.

Comment: I pasted into cell E6 the following formula: =IFERROR(INDEX('Predictions from GEF'!B12:B107,MATCH(ROW()-ROW($F$5),'Appendix 5 - 24 Hr Calc Data'!U12:U107,0)),"")

B12:B107 is the data I'm trying to transfer. U12:U17 is where the formula is that determines if the cell is empty.

Comment: It gives me a value of 0, when it should give me a value of 1000 (the value of B12).